# Using resttemplate to read the array of json objects where the array has not got name

Tags: json, resttemplate

I will get the response from the server as shown below. How to write the classes so that i can get this data using resttemplate. The thing is here the array has not got name.

```
[
    {
    "place_id": "",
    "licence": "",
    "osm_type": "",
    "osm_id": "",
    "boundingbox": [],
    "lat": "",
    "lon": "",
    "display_name": "",
    "class": "",
    "type": "",
    "icon": 
    "address": {
        "suburb": "",
        "village": "",
        "county": "",
        "state_district": "",
        "state": "",
        "country": "",
        "country_code": ""
        }
    },
    {
    "place_id": "",
    "licence": "",
    "osm_type": "",
    "osm_id": "",
    "boundingbox": [],
    "lat": "",
    "lon": "",
    "display_name": "",
    "class": "",
    "type": "",
    "icon": 
    "address": {
        "suburb": "",
        "village": "",
        "county": "",
        "state_district": "",
        "state": "",
        "country": "",
        "country_code": ""
        }
    }
]
```

and my controller class would look like this

```
Addresses[] response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Addresses[].class);
List<Addresses> objects = new ArrayList<Addresses>()
```

Comment: I think `"icon":` is missing a value.

Comment: did you solve this issue already?

Answer (score 0):

It doe's not matter how you call the outer class. I call it OuterType in my example:

```
package hello;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonNaming(LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy.class)
public class OuterType {
    // For simplicity properties are public
    public String placeId;
    public String licence;
    public String osmType;
    public String osmId;
    public BoundingBox[] boundingBox;
    public Address address;
}
```

restTemplate call:

```
OuterType[] response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, OuterType[].class);
```

Comment: @cse11 If you think my answer was helped you to solve the issue you can accept it, that will make it easier for other to find good answer and you will even get few points.